# navigating to anchor not working in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, anchor-scroll

I generated a link by using `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")#myAnchor'"`.

What happens is that the url is generated like this:

```
https://url.com/#myAnchor
```

Obviously the " / " is wrong, but even if I type the address manually in the address bar of any browser, it generates the above link.

I created a simple `<a href="#myAnchor">Link</a>` but that shows the same behavior.

So, how can I generate a link like `https://url.com#myAnchor` to get my view to scroll down to the given anchor?

Comment: What happens if you use `https://url.com/Home/Index#myAnchor` (assuming you have a `HomeController` and a default `Index` action)?

Comment: @PeterB isnt it good while set hardcoded url?

Comment: @PeterB:
This way, it does not put a " / " before #myAnchor, but does not scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 onclick="location.href='@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))#myAnchor'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this generates the same url like I mentioned above. Again a " / " is put at the end of the url, right before #myAnchor.

Comment: @WhoMightThisOneBe i guess it is correct formatting, can you please add your route config, and what controller name and action name you are using?

Comment: Oh my gosh, I´m so sorry.
I didn´t notice that the elements I was trying to navigate to didn´t have an id. The programmer who wrote the view didn´t set ids, but classnames. Thus a navigation was impossible.

Although it works now, the url is still generated with a " / ". But I don´t care as long as it works...

Thank you guys!

Comment: @WhoMightThisOneBe congrats, you found it.

Comment: Thanks ;) But what might be the reason for the false creation of the url?